# Use Super in emacs -nw in linux

Tags: key-bindings, linux, term, terminal-emacs

I have been struggling to find a simple and direct question to the answer and therefore I have decided to ask here.

**Q:** Is there a way to use Super in Emacs launched in a Terminal in Linux?

**P.S**: I read a lot of information about `xmodmap` but I think the key is that the terminal emulator cannot represent the Super key. However, `(kbd "s-SPC")` returns something and I was thinking of using the translation facility of `.Xdefaults/X`. Am I on the right path? Given the result of `kbd`, what do I need to put as XTerm.VT100.translations?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You will be more comfortable in an X11 Emacs, which can receive keyboard input and display text without going through [encoding and decoding for the terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116629/how-do-keyboard-input-and-text-output-work). The main reason to use a text mode editor is to run it inside screen or tmux on a remote machine, but thanks to Tramp, it's usually easier to edit the remote file in your local Emacs. That being said, you can do what you want as long as your terminal emulator cooperates, which is the case with Xterm.

When you press a key or key combination in a terminal, it is transmitted to the application running in the terminal as a sequence of one or more characters. For example, when you press <kbd>a</kbd>, the application receives `a`. When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the application receives the character `CR` (a.k.a. `^M` (pronounced “control-emm”), a.k.a. character number 13, a.k.a. `\r` or `\015`). Key combinations involving <kbd>Alt</kbd> are typically transmitted as the character `ESC` (a.ka. `^[` a.k.a. `\e` or `\033`) followed by the sequence for the key or key combination without <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Function keys and other key combinations are transmitted as escape sequences beginning with `\e[` or `\eO`.

The escapes sequences are not fully standardized, and terminals typically ignore certain attributes for certain keys. For example, the hyper and super modifiers are usually ignored. You can see what your terminal sends for a key combination by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by that key combination in a shell prompt, or `C-q` or `C-h c` followed by the key combination in Emacs.

Xterm lets you configure the escape sequences for each key through [X resources](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man7/X.7.html#sect13). Most setups read resources from `~/.Xresources` when X starts, and you can load the file manually with `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`.

```
XTerm.VT100.translations:       #override \n\
    Ctrl ~Shift ~Meta <Key> Return: string("\033[73;5~") \n\
    Ctrl Shift ~Meta <Key> percent: string("\033[37;6~")
```

A common convention uses escape sequences of the form `ESC [ number1 ; number2 ~` for function keys with modifiers. `number1` indicates the function key (`15` to `24` for <kbd>F5</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> — for historical reasons, F1 through <kbd>F4</kbd> have different escape sequences) and `number2` indicates the modifier (`2` for <kbd>Shift</kbd>, `5` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, `3` for <kbd>Meta</kbd>, `8` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>, and add 1 for +<kbd>Shift</kbd> — no, it isn't very consistent).

You'll have to specify the Hyper and Super modifiers through their number, as `Mod1` through `Mod5`. Run `xmodmap -pm` to see the mapping of keysyms to modifiers. For example, if `Super_L` is bound to Mod5, then the following line (use this exact case) defines a binding for <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>:

```
    ~Ctrl ~Meta Mod5 <Key> space: string("\033[32;16~") \n\
```

Emacs translates escape sequences into its internal key representation through [`input-decode-map` or `local-function-key-map`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html) (or `function-key-map` before Emacs 23).

```
(define-key local-function-key-map "\033[32;16~" [(super ?\ )])
```

<sub>This post is made of 80% recycled material from [Are there any linux terminals which can handle all key combinations?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79374/are-there-any-linux-terminals-which-can-handle-all-key-combinations/79561#79561)</sub>

Comment: This is a great answer, encompassing all the knowledge I found a little bit scattered around. Just one question: where did you find/how did you choose 32;16~ and why is it not matching with the emacs binding below?
I understood the origin of the numbers but I would like to ask you whether you can link to a mapping table somewhere for **number1** and **number2**.

Comment: @AndreaRichiardi I picked 32 because it's the ASCII/Unicode value for the space character and 16 because standard bindings use values up to 8 for Ctrl, Meta and Shift. The 33 below was a typo. You can pick anything as long as it doesn't conflict with other keys.

Comment: I had to bind the sequence to a function so I momentarily solved with ```(global-set-key "\033[32;16~" 'set-rectangular-region-anchor)```.
But to be complete, I tried your ```define-key``` above, but I couldn't then trigger ```(global-set-key (kbd "s-SPC") 'set-rectangular-region-anchor)```. It was just printing ;16~ in the buffer. It would have been nice to bind that sequence to (kbd "s-SPC") so that I have the key sequence bound and I can re-assign it to other commands.

Comment: ```C-h l``` returns the following on pressing s-SPC now:  ```ESC [ 3 2 ; 1 6 ~``` but emacs still complains that ```M-[ 32 is undefined```

Comment: @AndreaRichiardi After fixing more typos in the xterm part (which you seem to have fixed since Emacs receives the intended character sequence), it works for me. Does it work if you use `function-key-map` instead of `local-function-key-map`? It may be a matter of when you set `local-function-key-map`, as it's terminal-dependent.

Comment: In general works...can you set ```(global-set-key (kbd "s-SPC") 'set-rectangular-region-anchor)``` ?

Comment: @AndreaRichiardi Works for me with a `.emacs` containing the two lines `(define-key local-function-key-map "\033[32;16~" [(super ?\ )]) (global-set-key (kbd "s-SPC") 'set-rectangular-region-anchor)` and starting `emacs -nw` under Emacs 23.3.1.

Comment: Nope, I did exactly the same in my bindings file (I actually use emacs-live Version 1.0beta26 and emacs 24.3) and it prints ```16~```.

Comment: I forgot to mark this as solution sorry. You have moar points now and tnEms for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to install an Emacs package and configure your terminal, I wrote an Emacs package which can teach Emacs and terminals how to properly recognize all PC keyboard keys and modifier key combinations:

https://github.com/CyberShadow/term-keys

Encoding the Super modifier is not enabled by default, but the package is customizable and allows configuring which modifier key combinations are encoded. To enable encoding key combinations that include the Super modifier, set `term-keys/want-key-p-func` to a function which returns `t` when `(elt mods 3)` is non-nil (see [the default implementation](https://github.com/CyberShadow/term-keys/blob/d44bd242b06dd7544a1fe7be23c762f3463ff28c/term-keys.el#L229) for an explanation).

Answer (score 1):

I have the following in my init files:

```
(global-set-key [f7] nil)
(global-set-key [f8] nil)
(define-key function-key-map [(f7)] 'event-apply-super-modifier)
(define-key function-key-map [(f8)] 'event-apply-hyper-modifier)
```

This allows me to send super and hyper keys using the function keys.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use `Konsole`.

Explanation:

- Emacs' `local-function-key-map` has an entry mapping `C-x @ s` to `event-apply-super-modifier`.
- `Konsole` maps `Super` (the Windows logo key) to the escape sequence `^X@s` (which doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, I discovered it by chance). You can try this by opening `Konsole` and pressing e.g. <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> <kbd>Win-o</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but changing the term is not the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from @ubolonton's answer, I was able to bind `Super` and `Hyper` (and add a supplementary Meta key) in urxvt with those 4 lines of `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
URxvt.keysym.XF86AudioPlay: string:\030@m
URxvt.keysym.Menu: string:\030@s
URxvt.keysym.Muhenkan: string:\030@h
```

and out of luck I dind't had to touch anything else to make it work.

Explanation:

On my keyboard (a TypeMatrix), under `Shift_L, z, x, c` I have: `ctrl, XF86AudioPlay, Menu, Muhenkan` (weird keyboard), so by binding the strings `C-x @ m` to `XF86AudioPlay`, `C-x @ s` to `Menu` and `C-x @ h` to `Muhenkan`, I have, from the left to the right: Ctrl, Meta, Super, Hyper.

(If you have the exact same keyboard as mine and want to try it out, you first need to set your keyboard to its 106-keys layout by pressing `Fn-F3`, else the 4th key is bound to `Meta-tab`.)