# In terminal, C-) and ) both execute evil-forward-sentence. I want C-) to run paredit-forward-slurp-sexp

Tags: key-bindings, evil, terminal-emacs, paredit

If I type `C-f paredit-forward-slurp-sexp`, Emacs tells me the command is mapped to `C-)`. Yet through `C-h k` I realized that both `C-)` and `)` run `evil-forward-sentence`. If I do `C-f evil-forward-sentence`, Emacs tells me it is bound only to `)`.

If I evaluate `(key-binding (kbd "C-)"))` the result is `paredit-forward-slurp-sexp`. If I go through what `describe-bindings` prints, C-) is shown as associated with `paredit-forward-slurp-sexp`, There are other paredit associations in the listing, like `M-<right arrow>`, which works fine.

Why is this and how do I make the `C-)` behave the way I want.

Comment: On the topic of keyboard shortcuts in a terminal, see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5705/use-super-in-emacs-nw-in-linux and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/977/shiftup-isnt-recognized-by-emacs-in-a-terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evil keymaps override the default global keymaps. To learn more, you may want to read:

- [The Emacs manual on keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keymaps.html)
- [Mastering Emacs Key Bindings](http://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs)

If you want to override Evil keys, you'd need to do so to the Evil keymaps themselves:

```el
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-)") #'paredit-forward-slurp-sexp)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-)") #'paredit-forward-slurp-sexp)
(define-key evil-emacs-state-map (kbd "C-)") #'paredit-forward-slurp-sexp)
```

Comment: Evil does not define "C-)". It's that "C-)" gets interpreted the same way ")" does. I added more details to the question.

Comment: @user7610 are you using Emacs in a terminal, or graphically?

Comment: You are right! C-) works in the GUI and not in terminal. Do you know why?

Comment: @user7610 Yes. The short of it is that terminals have no way to express `C-)`. They lack the escape codes necessary to convey those keys to Emacs. You'll find that this is true of quite a few keybindings. Most `C-S-key` combos don't work. (Take `C-S-d`, which is passed as `C-d`). Long term, I'd recommend running the GUI version if you possibly can. Vim is a terminal editor that has a graphical mode. Currently, Emacs is a graphical editor that can run in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

As @PythonNut says in the comments below his or her answer, terminals don't have an escape code for `C-)`. It is necessary to either remap to something like `M-)` or use Emacs GUI.

It can be quickly checked by pressing `C-v` (outside of Emacs) which makes the terminal print the escape sequence for the shortcut that follows. `C-v C-)` and `C-v )` both print the same escape sequence, which happens to be a literal `)`.